# Powershell - How to get a value out of an object

Tags: powershell, windows-clustering

Newbie here. I'm sure the answer to this question exists elsewhere but I'm not situationally aware enough to find it.

I have a command:

```
PS C:\> Get-ClusterSharedVolume "Cluster Disk 1" | select -Expand SharedVolumeInfo | select -Expand Partition | select PercentFree
```

It returns this:

```
PercentFree

-----------
15.33617
```

Due to some limitations in another system that is taking this result as input, I would like it to say:

```
PercentFree:15.33617
```

How do I do that? Better yet, how do I just pop it into a variable like, "$freespace"?

Bonus question: How do I make it just say "15"? I've seen {0:N0} work in other scripts but my newbiness prevents me from understanding how I might apply it to this scenario :-)

Thanks!

Comment: I've found a very convoluted solution by putting my command's result into $a, then doing, "$b = [regex]::match($a,'\d\d').Groups[0].Value", then "echo 'PercentFree:$b". Far from an elegant solution, so I'm still happy to hear if anyone can explain any further!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to a cluster at the moment, does this works for you?

```
$pf = Get-ClusterSharedVolume "Cluster Disk 1" | Foreach-Object {$_.SharedVolumeInfo.Partition.PercentFree}    
$freespace = 'PercentFree:{0:N0}' -f $pf
```

Try this if the above doesn't work (based on your command):

```
$pf = Get-ClusterSharedVolume "Cluster Disk 1" | select -Expand SharedVolumeInfo | select -Expand Partition | select PercentFree
$freespace = 'PercentFree:{0:N0}' -f $pf.PercentFree
```

Comment: I like that solution because I think I understand it! Alas, $freespace ends up being "PercentFree:" without the actual value.

Comment: What do you get when you print $pf?

Comment: Nothing. echo $pf spits out a blank.

Comment: Also, taking out the $pf= leads to nothing being returned. "Get-ClusterSharedVolume "Cluster Disk 1" | Foreach-Object {$_.SharedVolumeInfo.Partition.PercentFree}" returns nada.